# Loss Function Not Decreasing in CNN

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, pytorch

I am new to Pytorch and I'm training a model for binary classification of images. The images are currently stored as .npy files and I am loading them and training my model in batches. When I implement this, the loss function does not decrease. When I test the model on the training and test set again, the accuracy is constant at 50%. The data set is balanced.

I tried making the dataset smaller (around 125 for each class) and I still have the same problem. I expect the model to overfit the training set but this does not occur.

Please see my code below

```
class Network(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Network,self).__init__()
        self.conv1=nn.Conv2d(in_channels=2, out_channels=32, kernel_size=3)
        self.conv2=nn.Conv2d(in_channels=32, out_channels=64, kernel_size=3)
        self.conv3=nn.Conv2d(in_channels=64, out_channels=128, kernel_size=3)
        self.fc1=nn.Linear(in_features=128*6*6, out_features=1000)
        self.fc2=nn.Linear(in_features=1000, out_features=100)
        self.out=nn.Linear(in_features=100, out_features=2)
    def forward(self,t):
        POOL_stride=2
        #Conv1
        t=F.relu(self.conv1(t))
        t=F.max_pool2d(t, kernel_size=2, stride=POOL_stride)
        #Conv2
        t=F.relu(self.conv2(t))
        t=F.max_pool2d(t, kernel_size=2, stride=POOL_stride)
        #Conv3
        t=F.relu(self.conv3(t))
        t=F.max_pool2d(t, kernel_size=2, stride=POOL_stride)
        # dense 1
        t=t.reshape(-1, 128*6*6)
        t=self.fc1(t)
        t=F.relu(t)
        #dense 2
        t=self.fc2(t)
        t=F.relu(t)
        t=self.out(t)
        return t

def npy_loader(path):
    sample = torch.from_numpy(np.load(path))
    return sample

criterion=nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(self.model.parameters(), lr=0.003)
model = Network()
trainset = datasets.DatasetFolder(
            root=train_dir,
            loader=npy_loader,
            extensions=['.npy']
        )
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
            trainset,
            batch_size=batch_size,
            shuffle=True,
        )
for epoch in range(epochs):
            running_loss = 0
            batches = 0
            for inputs, labels in train_loader:
                batches = batches+1
                inputs, labels = inputs.to(device), labels.to(device)
                optimizer.zero_grad()
                output = model(inputs)
                loss = criterion(output.squeeze(), labels.squeeze())
                loss.backward()
                optimizer.step()
                running_loss += loss.item()    
            print('Loss :{:.4f} Epoch[{}/{}]'.format(running_loss/batches, epoch, epochs))
'''
```

Answer (score 0):

You are providing parameters of some other `self.model` to optimizer while the model used for calculating the loss is different.

```
optimizer = optim.Adam(self.model.parameters(), lr=0.003)
model = Network()
```

Above is your sequence of defining `optimizer` and `model`. Notice that you are passing parameters of a different `self.model` to `optimizer`. Hence, `optimizer.step()` fails to update weights of desired `model` on which loss is being calculated. Instead it should be something like this:

```
model = Network()    
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.003)
```

On another note, might I suggest that instead of returning 2 dimensional output from model, returning a 1-d output and using binary cross-entropy loss can also be explored, as your task is only a binary classification problem.